# class weights formula for imbalanced dataset

Tags: deep-learning, class-imbalance, loss-function, weight-initialization

I am trying to make some semantic segmentation. I have 7 imbalanced classes in my case.
I found several methods for handling Class Imbalance in a dataset is to perform Undersampling for the Majority Classes or Oversampling for the minority classes. but the most used one is introducing weights in the Loss Function. And I found several formula to calculate weights such us:
wj=n_samples / (n_classes * n_samplesj)
or wj=1/n_samplesj

which is the best one?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't suggest Under/Oversampling as it would change the distribution of dataset. we should consider distribution as a useful feature of dataset. so I think the weighted loss would have better performance in most cases. if you're using TF/Keras, [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#class_weights) would be useful. you can use a variety of loss functions, like the below one, to apply the weight.

```
tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    labels, logits, pos_weight, name=None
)
```

> A value pos_weight > 1 decreases the false negative count, hence increasing the recall. Conversely setting pos_weight < 1 decreases the false positive count and increases the precision.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Actually, I have to introduce manually the class weights as a Tensor, and I don't no which formula I have to use?

Comment: the one you mentioned in your question is the one which is also introduced in the link I put from TF and works okay based on my experience `w_j=n_samples / (n_classes * n_samples_j)`. but you can think of it as a hyperparameter so using the resulted weights, you might still need some tests and trials to find the best values for weights in order to get the highest accuracy.

Comment: In fact on three classes it works really well. but when I go to the seven classes, I have the impression that it no longer works, for example I have a tensor of
weight = [1.0, 2.51, 8.52, 2.83, 168.53, 469.19, 1.35] for the seven classes ,

do we need to standardize them?

Comment: hmm, I guess it is better to reduce 168 and 469 to something less than 100 or 80. it needs a kind of test and trial. I just use the weight function to get an idea about weights.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !